# RMAN backup restore in a different node with datafiles and redolog files to a different directory

Tags: oracle, database-restore, data-files, rman, redo-logs

I can't restore the datafiles and redolog files from backup.
In RMAN I wrote,

```
run{
set newname for datafile 1 to '/u02/data_redo/system01.dbf';
set newname for datafile 2 to '/u02/data_redo/sysaux01.dbf';
set newname for datafile 3 to '/u02/data_redo/undotbs01.dbf';
set newname for datafile 4 to '/u02/data_redo/users01.dbf';
set newname for datafile 5 to '/u02/data_redo/example01.dbf';
sql "alter database rename file '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/db01/redo01.log' to 
'/u02/data_redo/redo01.log'";
sql "alter database rename file '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/db01/redo02.log' to 
'/u02/data_redo/redo02.log'";
sql "alter database rename file '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/db01/redo03.log' to 
'/u02/data_redo/redo03.log'";
restore database;
switch datafile all;
recover database; 
}
```

But it says,

```
using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
sql statement: alter database rename file 
'/u01/app/oracle/oradata/db01/redo01.log' to '/u02/data_redo/redo01.log'
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03009: failure of sql command on default channel at 07/30/2017 16:18:19
RMAN-10015: error compiling PL/SQL program
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
restore database
LOGFILE GROUP 1 ('/u/prog/oracle/oralog/MOBI6/redo01a.log') SIZE 100M, GROUP 2 ('/u/prog/oracle/oralog/MOBI6/redo02a.log') SIZE 100M;
...
```

Or you can set the init parameter

```
LOG_FILE_NAME_CONVERT=('/u02/','/disk2/')
```

Answer (score 0):

I know is an old question, but has worked using two single quotes before and after the file name and double quotes when opening and closing the SQL command.

Ex:

```
sql "alter database rename file ''+DATA/MOOTDB/ONLINELOG/group_6.268.1067716075'' to ''+DGDATAMOTHIST/MOTHIST/ONLINELOG/group_6_member_1.log''";
```